# Using jquery slidetoggle on visibility hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out a way to use slideToggle on elements which are set to visibility: hidden, rather than display: none.

The reason is because the text which is slidetoggling is causing the div it is within to stretch out. Is there any method I can use to keep the element which I want to slidetoggle to slide within its place without the div expanding?

HTML:

```
<section id="image-gallery">
            <div class="container">
            <div id="imageboxing" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/boxing.png">
            <h3>BOXING</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="imagekb" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/kickboxing.png">
            <h3>KICKBOXING</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="muaythai" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/muaythai.png">
            <h3>MUAYTHAI</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="wrestling" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/wrestling.png">
            <h3>WRESTLING</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".disciplines img").hover(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();


    })



});
```

Comment: where's the jquery that you've tried?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or similar in order to give us dev room to solve your problem as well?

Comment: I have updated the code to include my jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `h3` element inside a `div`:

```
<div>
  <h3>BOXING</h3>
</div>
```

And then give it a fixed height:

```
.disciplines div {
  height: 50px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to modify your selector to:

```
$('h3', this.parent).slideToggle();
```

or:

```
$(this).next().find('h3').slideToggle();
```

or something similar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".disciplines img").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().find('h3').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.disciplines div {
  height: 50px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="image-gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="imageboxing" class="disciplines">
      <img src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png">
      <div>
        <h3>BOXING</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="imagekb" class="disciplines">
      <img src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png">
      <div class="fh">
        <h3>KICKBOXING</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I can see how this would work, David. Only thing is, I'm not sure how I would target this with the jquery selector. What would I need to modify the selector to from my original  $(this).next().slideToggle(); ??? Thanks

Comment: @CoderAz I have edited my answer to include a new selector.